# Declaring variables in HeidiSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, heidisql

Regarding **HeidiSQL** I would like to set a variable to the maxdate of a table in order to use this variable as a 'WHERE'-criteria in another query.

I am using the following code

```
DECLARE @maxdate timestampz
SET @maxdate = (SELECT MAX("Date") FROM transactions)
SELECT maxdate
```

However, I get a syntax error at or near "@" in line 1.
Any help is much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Are you using Postgresql or Heidisql?

Comment: The SQL language does not support variables. So the only way to do this, would be if your query tool (=HeidiSQL) supported that. But there is nothing built into Postgres to do this.

Comment: I am using Heidisql